# How to restart cycling javascript cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I don't know how to make the title clearer, even though the question itself seems clear enough for me.

I've been using this jQuery plugin:

http://felix-kling.de/blog/2011/04/14/jQuery-Function-Toggle-plugin/

to make up for the toggle function that has been deprecated and removed in jQuery.

then I have the following function:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("span.letra").funcToggle('click',     
        function() {$(this).addClass("ex1");},
        function() {$(this).removeClass("ex1").addClass("ex2")},
        function() {$(this).removeClass("ex2").addClass("ex3")},
        function() {$(this).removeClass("ex3")}
    );
});
</script>
```

I use classes because I have this logic applied to many elements, although I only want the clicked ones to go through the cycle each time they're clicked.

Each class adds a different background-color to the element.

Now right after the elements I have a "clean all" button, that will remove every class of every one of those elements, returning them all to an "unclicked" state.

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("span.limpar").click(     
        function() {$("span.letra").removeClass("ex1 ex2 ex3");}
    );
});
</script>
```

Now what this button does, as you can see above, is remove every class that any of the elements might have.

Now for my problem:

Let's suppose I click an element twice. In the end the clicked element has the "ex2" class applied to it.

Now let's suppose I hit the "clean all" button, activating the second script above. It removes the "ex2" class previously applied to it by my clicks.

Now if I click **the same element** again, the click goes through like a **third** click, activating the third function in the funcToggle script.

What I'd like is code that not only cleans the classes from all the relevant elements, but also restarts the funcToggle script so any click on an already-clicked element will register as a first click in that sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there's another reason you're using funcToggle, but it seems to be more of a hindrance than a help for this particular job.

Here's another way to do it.

```
$('span.letra').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if($this.is('.ex1,.ex2,.ex3')) {
    $this.filter('.ex3').toggleClass('ex3');
    $this.filter('.ex2').toggleClass('ex2 ex3');
    $this.filter('.ex1').toggleClass('ex1 ex2');
  }else{
    $this.toggleClass('ex1');
  }
});
```

Storing the state in exactly one place (like the set of classes on the element) is usually better for your sanity than trying to keep multiple systems synchronized.

That said, if you want less repetition, you could do something like this:

```
$('span.letrb').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var ex = (1 + parseInt($this.data('ex') || 0)) % 4;
  $this.data('ex', ex);
  $this.removeClass('ex1 ex2 ex3');
  if (ex > 0) {
    $this.addClass('ex'+ex);
  }
});
```

This requires that you remember to reset both the data and the classes at the same time, too:

```
$('span.letrb').removeClass('ex1 ex2 ex3').data('ex', 0);
```

Comment: Of course if you don't actually _need_ the `ex1` `ex2` `ex3` classes for anything else (e.g., you can style them with `[data-ex=1]`), @roko-c-buljan's very first answer is exactly what you want.

Comment: I tried the 'data' solution below but could not get it to work; these functions worked right away using classes, the infrastructure I already had in place, so I guess it was more failsafe and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `class` or using `data-*` attribute.

Using the `data-*` attribute is easier cause you use a single-valued `data-ex` attr. while using classes you need to do complicated stuff to match the exact className, replace the right class (leaving other classes untouched) etc.

### Using data-* attribute (easiest):

```js
var $letra = $("span.letra");

$letra.click(function(){
  $(this).attr('data-ex', function(i, v){
    return v? ++v%4 : 1;
  });
});

$('.limpar').click(function(){
  $letra.attr("data-ex", "");
});
```

```css
.letra{
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:20px;
    background:#eee;
    margin:10px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

[data-ex='1']{background:yellow;}
[data-ex='2']{background:orange;}
[data-ex='3']{background:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="limpar">LIMPAR</button><br>

<span class="letra">Letra</span>
<span class="letra">Letra</span>
<span class="letra">Letra</span>
```

### Using class:

So you have three classes `ex1`, `ex2` and `ex3`?

Add with jQuery a dummy `ex0` class
<sup>*(P.S: If you want you can style the `ex0` class in CSS with the default stylings).*</sup>
*Why?* Cause than you can read the number out of the `ex*` class, increase that number and replace that class with the increased one.
Use Reminder Operator (Modulo) `%4` to loop your three classes:

```js
var $letra = $("span.letra");

$letra.addClass("ex0").click(function(){ // Assign 'ex0' Class and Click listener
  $(this).attr('class', function(i, v){  // Modify Class Value...
    return v.replace(/ex\d+/, "ex"+ (++v.match(/ex(\d+)/)[1] % 4));
  });
});

$('.limpar').click(function(){
  $letra.attr("class", function(i, v){
    return v.replace(/ex\d+/, "ex0"); // Set back to the dummy 'ex0' Class
  });
});
```

```css
.letra{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px;
  background:#eee;
  margin:10px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.ex1{background:yellow;}
.ex2{background:orange;}
.ex3{background:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="limpar">LIMPAR</button><br>


<span class="letra">ex0</span>
<span class="letra">ex0</span>
<span class="letra ex1">ex1</span>
<span class="letra ex2">ex2</span>
<span class="letra ex3">ex3</span>
```

Comment: I tried the 'data' method but could not get it to work. It is perhaps a fault on my side, for the code snippet clearly runs perfectly here - but I tried the other answer and it worked out ok. I wanted to vote this answer up but apparently 15 reputation is required, so I cannot do it =/ Thank you so much anyway!

Comment: @PetersonSilva :( the easiest way was usign data. That way you don't need to repeat all over again classNames inside functions etc like you need to in the other answer. But Anyways thx!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(function cycle(elem, clear, arr) {
    // clear classes , reset `cycle`
    clear.one("click.toggle", function () {
        console.log("clear all");
        elem.removeClass(arr.join(" "))
        .clearQueue("toggle").trigger("click.toggle")
    });
    return $.when(elem.queue("toggle", $.map(arr.concat($.noop())
        , function (val, key) {
            return function (next) {
                return $(this).one("click.toggle", function (e) {
                    // add current class, remove previously added class,
                    // call next item in `toggle` queue
                    return $(e.target).addClass(val).removeClass(arr[key - 1]) 
                           && next()
                });
            }
        })
    // return `toggle` promise, `clear`
    ).dequeue("toggle").promise("toggle"), clear, arr)
        .then(function (elem, clear, arr) {
        // `cycle` done , do stuff ,
        // remove added classes , reset `cycle`
        console.log("done");
        clear.off("click.toggle");
        return elem.removeClass(arr.join(" ")) && cycle(elem, clear, arr) 
    });
}($("span.letra"), $("span.limpar"), ["ex1", "ex2", "ex3"]));
```

```js
(function cycle(elem, clear, arr) {
    clear.one("click.toggle", function () {
        console.log("clear all");
        elem.removeClass(arr.join(" "))
        .clearQueue("toggle").trigger("click.toggle")
    });
    return $.when(elem.queue("toggle", $.map(arr.concat($.noop()), function (val, key) {
        return function (next) {
            return $(this).one("click.toggle", function (e) {
                return $(e.target).addClass(val).removeClass(arr[key - 1]) && next()
            });
        }
    })).dequeue("toggle").promise("toggle"), clear, arr)
        .then(function (elem, clear, arr) {
        console.log("done");
        clear.off("click.toggle");
        return elem.removeClass(arr.join(" ")) && cycle(elem, clear, arr) 
    });
}($("span.letra"), $("span.limpar"), ["ex1", "ex2", "ex3"]));
```

```css
.ex1 {
    background-color:red;
}
.ex2 {
    background-color:green;
}
.ex3 {
    background-color:blue;
}
.letra {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid purple;
    display:block;
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align:center;
}
.limpar {
    background:yellow;
    border:1px solid #000;
    display:block;
    width:136px;
    padding:7px;
    margin-top:1px;
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:center;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="letra">click</span>
<span class="limpar">clear all</span>
```

Comment: This gives me " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of null "